# For some reason my image is "morphed" and looks different in different browers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

So my logo login image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNQTe.jpg look different in chrome and edge. The "login" part is part of the image. The "login" part is shifted for some reason and it should appear as it does in chrome. I am super confused as how could a browser morph my image like that.  I designed it in adobe xd and export it as an svg to react project. (the zoom is 100% on both and it displays correctly in safari and google chrome on my phone). The font of "login" though is different on safari. If the login is part of the image why can it be changed by different browers?

Comment: SVG is a vector format, not a pixel format. A simple way to fix this is to export the image as PNG instead.